# How to remove window screens?

Tags: windows, removal, new-home, building, screens

We have a brand new house. The window screens were installed by the builder as something of an afterthought after we closed. We only recently tried to remove a screen and realized they don’t budge. We have single paned windows that slide up and the screens have little locks at the top and tabs at the bottom.

Every screen I’ve ever dealt with that has tabs also had a spring opposite and it was just a matter of pushing toward the springs and easing the screen out on whichever side is open. But these won’t move. They move up slightly but seem to be too wide to squeeze past the frame, which is open on the inside. I’ve managed to finesse a single corner at the bottom of one but the top doesn’t follow. I realize I can fit something in the gap and work the screen out but that’s one window and it seems kinda hazardous not to be able to just pull the screen out if there’s a fire or something and we need to get out.

So the question is whether I’m missing something about these screens or whether the builder hired some incompetent who put in the wrong kind. We might have a case for getting replacements if that’s what happened. There’s one downstairs that doesn’t cover properly anyway. [image]

Comment: We had new new windows put in years ago and came with screens in them.  They are held on by leaf springs and are a PITA to remove(by hand, without breaking something).

Answer (score 0):

typically push the screen frame up and to the side until one of the bottom corners comes loose. then pop that corner out and go the other direction.